# Tune XGB Parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am working on a project with a dataset of aircraft engines and their lifetime. I need to use XGBRegressor to have the highest success rate of my model on my validation data.

I am having trouble understanding the XGBRegressor documentation, I was wondering if you know how I could optimize the search for optimal parameters instead of testing everything by hand.

I attached a part of my code related to XGB.

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
xgb = XGBRegressor(learning_rate = 0.3, max_depth = 7, n_estimators = 230, subsample = 0.7, colsample_bylevel = 0.7, colsample_bytree = 0.7, min_child_weight = 4, reg_alpha = 10, reg_lambda = 10)
xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @pixlnoob does my answer address your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer will help you achieve this; you can add more Hyperparameters or more classifiers to test with different approaches. if you set `cv=5` it will do 5-fold cross validation; but if you have a specific validation and only want to get perfect results you can add pass this to cv:

```
indices = np.arange(len(X_train))
train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(indices, test_size=0.2)
cv_indices=[(train_idx, test_idx)]
```

otherwise use: `cv=5` to do 5-fold CV while searching for parameters.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
dict_classifiers = {
    "XGB": XGBRegressor()
}

params = {

    "XGB": {'min_child_weight': [1, 5, 10],
            'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
            'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
            'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
            'max_depth': [3, 4, 5], "n_estimators": [300, 600],
            "learning_rate": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1],
            }

}


for classifier_name in dict_classifiers.keys() & params:

    print("training: ", classifier_name)
    gridSearch = GridSearchCV(
        estimator=dict_classifiers[classifier_name], param_grid=params[classifier_name], cv=cv_indices)
    gridSearch.fit(X_train, # shoud have shape of (n_samples, n_features) 
                   y_train.reshape((-1))) #this should be an array with shape (n_samples,)
    print(gridSearch.best_score_, gridSearch.best_params_)
```